# How to make synchronization with webservice

Tags: android, web-services, sqlite, retrofit

I'm struggling with this issue for almost 2 days.

I need to make a synchronization of a Android App with a Webservice as follows:

> The user press the sync button -> 3 refrotit calls are made (One for user Settings, another for Contacts and another for Address) -> The Settings, Contacts and Address are save into the SQLite Database -> A message box appears with a success message and a OK button -> When pressed, the OK button, star a new Activity

I already know how to make almos everything, the retrofit call, the insert on the Sqlite Database, create the message box, the only thing that I don't know how to do, is check when the Sqlite operation is finished (because there are many Contacts and it takes a few seconds to save them into the database), so I can call the message box, and if I should use retrofit asynchronous calls or synchronous, like One after another inside a AsyncTask?

This is what I've got so far:

```
// This is the method that makes the synchronization 
private void execToken() {
    // Gets a token to use in the requests
    final String token = edtToken.getText().toString();
    // Verify if the token is valid
    if (!EdtValidador.validateToken(token)) {
        txtInputToken.setError("Verifique seu Token");
        edtToken.requestFocus();
    } else {
        // If is valid, does the job
        txtInputToken.setErrorEnabled(false);
        // Creates a progress dialog using the MaterialDialog lib
        final MaterialDialog progressDialog;
        progressDialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
                .title("Verificando")
                .content("Aguarde")
                .cancelable(false)
                .progress(true, 0)
                .show();
        progressDialog.show();
        Log.i("ACTTOKEN", "ProgressDialog created");
        // Verifiy if the token is already in the database
        if (DBTeste.isTokenFilled(this, token)) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            // Creates a MessageBox saying that the token is already in the database
            MessageBox.showAlert(this, "Erro ao adicionar Token", "Token já cadastrado");
        } else {
            HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            // Cliente OkHttp usado para adicionar o interceptor do logger
            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
            okHttpClient.interceptors().add(logging);
            // Defines the Json date format
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
                    .create();
            // Creates the retrofit instance
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit
                    .Builder()
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .baseUrl(WebServiceConfig.webSerApiIP)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();
            final ConfigApi configApi = retrofit.create(ConfigApi.class);
            // Makes the first call using the token
            Call<Config> callConfig = configApi.getConfig(token);
            callConfig.enqueue(new Callback<Config>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response<Config> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                    // Config object receives the response
                    Config config = response.body();
                    // If isn't null adds on the database
                    if (config != null && config.getToken() != null) {
                        Log.i("ACTTOKEN", "Resultado da resposta de callConfig: " + config.getToken());
                        try {
                            // Inserts the ConfigObject in the database
                            DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(TokenActivity.this, token);
                            SQLiteDatabase conn = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                            RepositorioConfig repositorioConfig = new RepositorioConfig(conn);                                
                            repositorioConfig.inserirConfig(config);
                        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
                            // Returns the error in the log
                            Log.i("ACTTOKEN", "Erro ao inserir TOKEN no banco de dados local: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                        // Dismiss the MaterialDialog progressDialog
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    } else {
                        // Dismiss the progressDialog and shows another with a error message
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        MessageBox.showAlert(TokenActivity.this, "Token não encontrado", "Verifique o token informado");
                        Log.i("ACTTOKEN", "Erro ao baixar: Token inválido");
                        // Limpa o campo de texto
                    }
                }
                // In case of retrofit error
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    MessageBox.showAlert(TokenActivity.this, "Erro de conexão", "Verifique sua conexão de internet e tente novamente");
                    Log.i("ACTTOKEN", "Erro ao baixar: " + t.getMessage());
                }
            });
            ////////// Donloads the Contats and save \\\\\\\\\\
            final CadastroApi cadastroApi = retrofit.create(CadastroApi.class);
            Call<List<Cadastro>> callCadastro = cadastroApi.getCadastro(token);
            callCadastro.enqueue(new Callback<List<Cadastro>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response<List<Cadastro>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                    List<Cadastro> cadastroList = response.body();
                    if (cadastroList != null){
                        Log.i("ACTTOKEN", "Resultado da resposta de callCadastro: " + cadastroList.get(0));
                        try{
                            DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(TokenActivity.this, token);
                            SQLiteDatabase conn = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                            RepositorioCadastro repositorioCadastro = new RepositorioCadastro(conn);
                            // Inserts each item of the list in the database
                            for ( Cadastro c : cadastroList){
                                repositorioCadastro.inserirCadastro(c);
                                Log.i("ACTTOKEN", "Cadastro inserido: " + cadastroList.indexOf(c));
                            }
                        }catch (SQLiteException e){
                            Log.i("ACTTOKEN", "Erro ao inserir Cadastro(s) no banco de dados local: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                    Log.i("ACTTOKEN", "Erro retrofit ao baixar Cadastros " + t.getMessage());
                }
            });
            ////////// Download the address and save them \\\\\\\\\\
            final EnderecoApi enderecoApi = retrofit.create(EnderecoApi.class);
            Call<List<Endereco>> callEndereco = enderecoApi.getEndereco(token);
            callEndereco.enqueue(new Callback<List<Endereco>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response<List<Endereco>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                    List<Endereco> enderecoList = response.body();
                    if (enderecoList != null) {
                        try {
                            DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(TokenActivity.this, token);
                            SQLiteDatabase conn = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                            RepositorioEndereco repositorioEndereco = new RepositorioEndereco(conn);
                            // Insere cada item da lista no Banco de dados
                            for (Endereco e : enderecoList) {
                                repositorioEndereco.inserirEndereco(e);
                                Log.i("ACTTOKEN", "Endereço inserido: " + enderecoList.indexOf(e));
                            }
                        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
                            Log.i("ACTTOKEN", "Erro ao inserir Endereço(s) no banco de dados local: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                    Log.i("ACTTOKEN", "Erro retrofit ao baixar Endereços " + t.getMessage());
                }
            });
      }      
}
```

Comment: Added what I've got so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no exception has occurred during the insertion in the database (case in witch you would be thrown in the catch bloc) is completed when breaking your for each loop.

```
for (Endereco e : enderecoList) {
     repositorioEndereco.inserirEndereco(e);
}
//put your code right here!
```

Comment: Ok, but I put my code to open the dialog, right there, it wold be called in every one of the calls, making the message box apear one above the other, is there a way to check if it is open first?

Comment: ofc, just add a global  boolean variable to check if its the first one to be opened

Comment: But how? I can't figure out a way, I i set a boolean, how can i make check if it is true or not? I mean, I create outside off all calls, define it as false, and then recovery it and on each call, test  if it is already true, if yes -> do nothing, otherwise, open the dialog and set as true?

Comment: How man requests are u doing? if you can count the number o request you are doing just use a counter, increment it everytime a request is done (success or error) when it reaches the target count display your msgbox

Comment: I'm doing 4 at the time. So I'm gona do a test to see if the counter matches the number of requests, if not, increment. I'm right?

Comment: Tank you I will try this. One more thing,  the insert into the sqlite database can take a few seconds if the query have many items,  so can I wrap it in an extra try {} catch {}  block and do this into the finally block? So I is only called when the insert is done?

Comment: Why not as long as u find a way to tell your users if everything went as expected or if there are some errors.

Comment: Well it can work too, but I was worried about the query time because in some cases it have more than 600 registers and made the application drop almost 350 frames.

Comment: U can use an intent service to do the background work, and then notify your activity with a broadcast receiver here is some documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html